# Handle WM_KEYDOWN

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to get my program to toggle a bool if the shift key is pressed. However, for some reason it doesn't seem to be receiving the message, as I've put MessageBoxes in both the KEYDOWN and KEYUP cases, and they don't get triggered. This feels like something of a noob question, but any help would be appreciated.

```
BOOL CALLBACK CreateRoom(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
static char *achTileDetails = new char[100,100];
static POINT *pDimensions = new POINT, *pMonsterLocations = new POINT[10], *pMinDisplay = new POINT, *pMaxDisplay = new POINT;
static HBITMAP *pahbmTileset = new HBITMAP[4];
static bool *pbShowBars = new bool;
switch(Message)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    g_hDialogInUse = hwnd;
    SetFocus(hwnd);
    for (int iii = 0; iii < 100; iii++)
        for(int jjj = 0; jjj < 100; jjj++)
            achTileDetails[iii,jjj] = 'g';
    (*pDimensions).x = 20;
    (*pDimensions).y = 10;
    (*pMinDisplay).x = 0;
    (*pMinDisplay).y = 0;
    (*pMaxDisplay).x = 20;
    (*pMaxDisplay).y = 10;
    for (int iii = 0; iii < 4; iii++)
        pahbmTileset[iii] = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_CLEAR_GROUND + iii));
    return TRUE;
case WM_PAINT:
    DisplayRoom(hwnd, achTileDetails, *pMaxDisplay, *pMinDisplay, pahbmTileset, *pbShowBars);
    break;
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case IDCANCEL:
        delete[] achTileDetails;
        delete pDimensions;
        delete[] pMonsterLocations;
        delete pMinDisplay;
        delete pMaxDisplay;
        delete[] pahbmTileset;
        delete pbShowBars;
        EndDialog(hwnd, IDCANCEL);
        break;
    }
    break;
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:

    break;
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    MessageBox(hwnd, "Down", "", NULL);
    switch (wParam)
    {
    case VK_SHIFT:
        *pbShowBars = true;
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    }
    break;
case WM_KEYUP:
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, "Up", "", NULL);
        switch(wParam)
        {
        case VK_SHIFT:
            *pbShowBars = false;
            InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
            UpdateWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
default:
    return FALSE;
}
}
```

Message Loop:

```
 while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}
```

This is now the full code for this callback. I'm aware the various static dynamic variables at the top probably aren't the most effective way of doing this, but work for my purposes.

Comment: You are attempting to detect `VK_SHIFT`, the shift key. You need to look for `VK_SPACE` to respond to the space key.

As to why your `MessageBox` functions are not running, who could say? Unless you show more code, we'd just have to guess.  If you provided enough code for us to reproduce then we could answer the question. But right now this is a non-question. It's simple to provide a complete program the illustrates the fault. Please do so,

Comment: I've added the rest of the code for that callback. I didn't add the entire code as, just in that file, there are over 1,000 lines of code, not including various other function definitions. Should I also post my WinMain and WndProc functions?

Comment: Don't post 1000 lines of code. Post the smallest amount that demonstrates the issue. If you do that it will be trivial to solve.

Comment: But let's be clear, `CreateRoom` receives no `WM_KEYDOWN` messages?

Comment: The above code _should_ be sufficient to demonstrate the issue, as far as I'm aware. I can post additional code if necessary, but will be going AFK for a while, so my reply might be somewhat delayed

Comment: Not as far as I can tell, because it's not displaying the messageboxes. I could attempt breakpointing, but I doubt that would produce a different result.

Comment: Since you have `WM_INITDIALOG`, I assume this is a dialog box. Are you using [IsDialogMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? That might be the problem.

Comment: No it's not sufficient. Because we cannot compile it. And there's obviously something else going on, because plenty of people are receiving WM_KEYDOWN messages.

Comment: @JesseGood Where would I use IsDialogMessage? I can see it might come in useful, but I don't know where to place it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry, but there are about three dialogs and a window directly above it, not including WndProc and WinMain, as well as an awful lot of user defined functions. I could post all of this, but it seems like an excessive amount of code. If it would help, I could provide skeleton code for these windows, but actually making it compilable and usable seems like a hell of a lot of code.

Comment: As part of your message loop. However it is only for modeless dialog boxes, [see the example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) under `Creating a Modeless Dialog Box`.

Comment: Either you want help, or you don't. If you can't be bothered to make a compilable program that demonstrates the fault, you'll be relying on somebody's inspiration and guesswork. Frankly I think it's rude for you not to bother making a compilable example. It might take you an hour tops. What's stopping you? Is that too much effort?

Comment: @JesseGood This isn't a modeless DialogBox, so that function doesn't seem to make any difference. I might, however, have entered it in my message loop wrong. I'll add that code, and update the existing code

Comment: It's just a guess, but I have a feeling the shift key is a modifier key that does not fire an event itself but fires when you press another key simultaneously. For example, if you press shift+K, the KeyPress event fires with an uppercase K as its argument rather than a lowercase k. I'm not sure what you would have to do to detect the shift key press unfortunately.

Comment: @Steztric I've looked on MSDN, and they do give a message for shift. Also, I've tried pressing other keys, and this doesn't seem to display the MessageBoxes either, indicating that the problem is in how I'm handling WM_KEYDOWN

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `IsDialogMessage` then (your message loop is wrong, you should pass the message to `TranslateMessage`, etc. when it is not processed by `IsDialogMessage`). Also, `(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)` should be `(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)` (and you should handle when it returns negative) and `new char[100,100];` is wrong. I cannot see the rest of the code, so that is all I can help.

Comment: @JesseGood I realised the Message Loop was wrong and corrected it, and as it's not a modeless dialog, will delete `IsDialogMessage` altogether. Also, why is `new char[100,100]` wrong?

Comment: `new char[100,100]` is the same as `new char[100]`. The first `100` is ignored. If you turn up your warning level, you should get [a warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733923%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Comment: @JesseGood Are you sure? It's compiling, and when I've accessed it as `TileDetails[iii,jjj]` it's worked fine

Comment: `TileDetails[iii,jjj]` is legal C++, so there is no reason why it should not compile. It just happens to be the same meaning as `TileDetails[jjj]` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @JesseGood So how would I create that array correctly?

Comment: Also, any further advice on WM_KEYDOWN?

Comment: `static char achTileDetails[100][100];` The comment thread is getting too long, so I will stop.

Comment: @JesseGood OK, that makes sense. With respect to WM_KEYDOWN, would you prefer moving this to chat, as the site suggests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WM_KEYUP/DOWN messages are posted to the window that has the focus.  That is not going to be your dialog window, we can tell from the WM_COMMAND message handler that you have at least a Cancel button.  Which is very likely to get the focus.  That button doesn't do anything special with the message, other than you pressing the space bar.

This problem got started by using a dialog as your main window.  It isn't exactly a suitable window type to implement a game, it is suitable for dialogs.  Where the window just acts as a container, the work is done by the controls you put on the dialog.  You can rescue it by intercepting the message in your message loop, before it is dispatched to the window with the focus.  The TranslateAccelerator() function is the standard way to implement shortcut keystrokes.  Or by calling IsDialogMessage inside the loop and implementing a handler for WM_GETDLGCODE.

Comment: So essentially, I should reimplement this as a window rather than as a dialog? Incidentally, this is not my main window, it is simply one of a number of dialogs in use. I am using this as a modal dialog because I need to use the return value in a function below

Comment: If you need a dialog then you should use a dialog.  I can't really phantom what the code tries to do but surely a checkbox is a better way to allow the user to turns something on or off than an undiscoverable magic keystroke.  Make your UI usable and everything falls together easily.

Comment: OK, that would make sense. I was intending to include an instruction either on screen or in documentation, but considering the difficulty I'm having in implementing the keystroke, this method seems vastly superior.